# Configuration for maven and flyway in multiple environments, plus integration tests

Tags: maven, flyway

I have a multi-module Maven project and am using Flyway for db migration. Currently, I have this snippet in my pom.xml:

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>drop-db-before-test-if-any</id>
      <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <driver>${datasource.driver}</driver>
        <url>${datasource.url}</url>
        <username>${datasource.user}</username>
        <password>${dbPass}</password>
        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
        <srcFiles>
          <srcFile>${main.basedir}/db/test/drop_create_database_test.sql</srcFile>
        </srcFiles>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

How can I convert this to perform the equivalent of the following, such that it will use the flyway migration sql to better mimic production (in test currently it uses a db-test.properties where jpa.generate_ddl=true so that tables are auto-created from the JPA):

```html
mvn flyway:clean -P test
mvn flyway:init -Dflyway.initVersion=1 -Dflyway.initDescription="Initial Version" -P test
mvn flyway:migrate -P test
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then this is what you need.
This assumes that you have baselineOnMigrate=true in the plugin configuration.

`<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <driver>${datasource.driver}</driver>
                            <url>${datasource.url}</url>
                            <user>${datasource.username}</user>
                            <password>${datasource.password}</password>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>flyway-clean-database</id>
                                <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>clean</goal>
                                    <goal>migrate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>`